# ElasticSearch AWS request Timeout

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch instance running in AWS which I was able to connect to via the JavaScript client in a MeteorJS application. There was no issue creating mappings(indices and analyzers) or updating mappings.

The problem arises whenever there is an index, update or delete request to the instance. After serving above 200 request, the ElasticSearch instance starts throwing request timeout error with code 408. Initially, I thought making multiple single request is the casue, so I decided to do bulk push. Below is the snippet for the bulk push request.

```
var bulk = SearchService.ElasticQueue.splice(0, 1000);
console.log('Size: ', bulk.length);
if (bulk.length > 0) {
  EsClient.bulk({
    body: bulk
  }, function (error, response) {
    if (!error) {
      console.log(response);
    } else {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

The SearchService.ElasticQueue is a form of queue and a cron job runs frequently to fetch data from it and run bulk requests. I also tried reducing the number of documents in the bulk request and also increased request Timeout in the connection config, but it doesn't seem to help. I would appreciate any suggestion made.

Thanks.

Comment: we're seeing a timeout as well. can't find an explanation yet. times out after 30 seconds. did you find a solution yet?

Comment: It seems to be connectivity issue.

Comment: Same here. I'm using `curl` and having TIMEOUTS as well, but I did notice that records are randomly added to index. Any luck with resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way that you can use:

```
wait_for_completion=false
```

Which will return a `Task ID` and then you can pull the data using this `Task ID`